# Server uptime, need days only..Powershell

Tags: powershell

I currently have a script to return server up-time that is operating correctly, but when I receive a value for server up-time it includes days, minutes, and seconds.

Here is the line from the script that I think needs to be modified:

```
$os=Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem
$uptime=((get-date) - ($os.ConvertToDateTime($os.lastbootuptime))).tostring()
```

I have tried looking up options to only return days; but have been unable to find one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you subtract two datetimes you get a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) struct, that struct has a [Days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) property you can use.

```
$uptime = ((get-date) - ($os.ConvertToDateTime($os.lastbootuptime))).Days
```

If you want fractional days use [TotalDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) instead of Days, so if you have a day and a half you get `1.5` for a answer.

Answer (score 4):

Per http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2012/01/quick-way-to-find-server-up-time-in.html , try this:

```
(get-date)-([System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).lastbootuptime))|select days
```

Or are you looking for fractional days as well?

Comment: This works as well. Would up the answer if I had the rep. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Reads server lists from CSV file and get the uptime and generate report in HTML page.Which can be put on IIS or any web server to publish.

```
                #Html Page
                $now=get-date
                $table="<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Server Uptime Page</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><p align=Center><font size=6 face=Bodoni MT color=#003333><B>Server UpTime Report</B></font></p>"
                $table += "<p align=Center><font face=Bodoni MT color=Green size=3>Last pulled : $now EST</font></P>"
                $table +="<p align=Center><table BORDER=1 width=500 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>"
                $table +="<tr>"
                $table +="<th bgcolor=#303030 colspan=1 width=300><p align=center><b><font face=Verdana size=2 color=#FFFFFF>Server Name</font></b></p></th>"
                $table +="<th bgcolor=#303030 colspan=1 width=200><p align=center><b><font face=Verdana size=2 color=#FFFFFF>Up Time</font></b></p></th>"
                $table +="</tr>"
                $nNeedToReboot=0
                $nServerList=0
                $more100=""
                $bw75100=""
                $bw5075=""
                $bw3050=""
                $bw029=""
                $ErrorSvr=""
                $svrlist =get-content d:\PSScripts\Uptime\ServerList.csv  ##Source File

                $LastUpdatedSvrList=(dir d:\PSScripts\Uptime\ServerList.csv).lastwritetime
                foreach($svr in $svrlist)
                    {
                        if($svr -ne ""){
                        $nServerList++
                        $uptime=-1
                        $lastreboot=-1
                        $wmi=$null
                        #Write-Host "Server is $svr"
                        $wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $svr
                        $lastreboot=$wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootUpTime)
                        $uptime=($now-$lastreboot).days
                        $Svr+" : "+$uptime+" : "+$lastreboot
                            if($uptime -gt 99){
                                $nNeedToReboot++
                                $more100 += "<tr bgcolor='#FF0000'><td>"+$svr+"</td><td align=center>"+$uptime+"</td></tr>"
                                #Write-Host "$svr  $uptime"
                            }
                            if($uptime -gt 74 -AND $uptime -lt 100){
                                $nNeedToReboot++
                                $bw75100 += "<tr bgcolor='#E42217' ><td>"+$svr+"</td><td align=center>"+$uptime+"</td></tr>"
                                #Write-Host "$svr  $uptime"
                            }
                            if($uptime -gt 49 -AND $uptime -lt 75){
                                $nNeedToReboot++
                                $bw5075 += "<tr bgcolor='#C11B17'><td>"+$svr+"</td><td align=center>"+$uptime+"</td></tr>"
                                #Write-Host "$svr  $uptime"
                            }
                            if($uptime -gt 29 -AND $uptime -lt 50){
                                $nNeedToReboot++
                                $bw3050 += "<tr bgcolor='#DC381F'><td>"+$svr+"</td><td align=center>"+$uptime+"</td></tr>"
                                #Write-Host "$svr  $uptime"
                            }
                            if($uptime -gt -1 -AND $uptime -lt 30){             
                                $bw029 += "<tr bgcolor='#6CBB3C'><td>"+$svr+"</td><td align=center>"+$uptime+"</td></tr>"
                                #Write-Host "$svr  $uptime"
                            }
                            if($uptime -eq -1 -OR $lastreboot -eq -1){              
                                $ErrorSvr += "<tr bgcolor='#FF0000'><td>"+$svr+"</td><td align=center>Error connection</td></tr>"
                                #Write-Host "$svr  $uptime"
                            }
                    }
                    }
                    $table +=$more100+$bw75100+$bw5075+$bw3050+$bw029+$ErrorSvr
                $table+="</table>"
                $table +="<font size=2 face=Bodoni MT color=#003333><B>Servers in List : </B></font>$nServerList<br>"
                $table +="<font size=2 face=Bodoni MT color=#003333><B>Servers Need to be Rebooted : </B></font>$nNeedToReboot<br>"

                $table>c:\iis\Uptime.htm 
                Exit


                #########################END#############################
```